# How can I have a PHP page inside of an ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

We're migrating our existing PHP site to ASP.NET MVC. Rather than rebuild everything at once we'd like to be able to include some of our existing PHP applications inside of our new MVC project.

I've used the Windows Platform Installer to setup PHP support for IIS. I've tested this by putting a PHP file inside of the inetpub/wwwroot folder and it works well.

However, when I try add a PHP file to my MVC project and then access it in a browser it's downloading the file rather than running it.

Ignoring PHP files in the routing engine didn't solve this problem.

Anyone know how to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the MVC engine is trying to process your php file. I think maybe setting up *.php as an ignorable route would do the trick?

In global.asax.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.php/{*pathInfo}");

    // rest of route configuration
}
```

Comment: No luck... I thought that may be the case as well. I've tried this as well as placing the PHP file in the Content folder (which my understanding is that by default will ignore the MVC routing engine).

Comment: Then I don't think I can help. I'll probably delete my answer since it's wrong. You may want to edit your original post to indicate that ignoring .php in the route engine didn't work.

Comment: any luck getting around this @Hillel Coren